# Bypass Node Delete Confirm Form in Drupal

Tags: drupal

Looking for the best way to allow users to delete nodes on a site without the need to use a confirm form. I have tried using a form_alter to direct people to a custom submit function, without success.

Anyone ever tried this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming drupal 7, the node/%/delete menu entry is wired directly to the node_delete_confirm form.  You can modify it with with a hook_menu_alter, and change the function from drupal_get_form to a page callback of your own design that will just delete the node.

Example:

In your module file you'd need:

```
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['node/%node/delete']['page callback'] = 'my_node_delete_function';
  $items['node/%node/delete']['page arguments'] = array(1);
  $items['node/%node/delete']['module'] = 'mymodule';
  $items['node/%node/delete']['file'] = 'mymodule.pages.inc';
}
```

And in your mymodule.pages.inc file you'd need:

```
function my_node_delete_function($node) {
  // Taken from node modules node_delete_confirm submit handler
  node_delete($node->nid);
  watchdog('content', '@type: deleted %title.', array('@type' => $node->type, '%title' => $node->title));
  drupal_set_message(t('@type %title has been deleted.', array('@type' => node_type_get_name($node), '%title' => $node->title)));

  // Do a drupal goto here to preserver the 'destination' parameter
  drupal_goto();
}
```

Comment: Hi, how can I modify this code to skip this step only if the content type is == 'contentype'? I can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: @Shyghar : In your `my_node_delete_function`, use a condition: `if ($node->type == 'contenttype') { node_delete($node->nid); /*...*/ } else { /* confirmation form before delete */ }`